# How to set the value of h:selectOneRadio using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

I have a JSF application in which I need to change the state of the page when an event occurs - in this case I need to select a specific radio button from JS using JQuery - I tried the following code but it does not appear to work - can anyone assist.

```
var radioButton = $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('f:t:radioButton1'));
radioButton.prop("value","F");
```

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't that `radioButton.val('F')`?

Comment: JSF doesn't render a SelectOneRadio as a regular <input type="radio">, you check it using an inspector... What i would suggest you is to use ajax to update your radio with a function in your bean. I'm not sure if it can be done only with JS